# Upload Django webapp to azure

Tags: django, azure, visual-studio-2015

I made a Django webapp in PyCharm and after 6 hours of trying I finally got it to work in visual studio 2015.
Now i'm trying to upload it to Azure via VS. 
this is what I get:

```
------ Publish started: Project: TryDjango, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I get no Warnings, no Errors and no messages.
I don't think there is anyone that can help. But please try!

Comment: But what error are you facing when try to publish the site?  please complete your question

Comment: @JuanK None. It just says failed.

Comment: Have you reviewed azure website logs ? review them and then please share some related contents.

Comment: @JuanK I don't have access to them at the moment.(I'm on my phone). But i'll post them asap.

Comment: @juanK I checked the logs but there wasn't anything in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked on multiple fora, and I have tried a lot. But **nothing** worked. So I "rewrote" my app.


But as a very lazy person, I didn't feel like writing everything again. So I created a new Django site in **virtual studio** *It has to be done in VS, I don't know why.*


I then imported the first django project into VS. Using the copy tool in VS, I copied the apps *Not the whole project, just the apps. again this has to be done within VS*


I updated the settings & urls and it seems to work.
I don't know why the `python.importexistingproject` doesnt work, but this does.

Answer (score 0):

copy my answer from [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a866c6c0-094f-4a2d-8dd8-d7f3f74f053d/upload-django-webapp-to-azure?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

not an expert on Django, but alternatively you can try to deploy your application via continues deployment, below is an tutorial

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

you can also checkout below "Creating web apps with Django in Azure" tutorial to see if you miss anything.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/